# Uniqueness of inverse of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, inverse-function

Let $V,W$ be real vector spaces, and consider an $\Bbb R$-linear transformation $\varphi:V\to W$.

We know that if $\varphi$ is both left and right invertible, then it admits an inverse and it is unique.

If $\varphi$ is invertible on one side (for example on the right), it can be proved this right inverse is not in general unique.

My question is: if we know that this right inverse is unique, does it imply that $\varphi$ is also left invertible?

I suspect linear spaces/maps don't play any relevant role here; maybe this result, can be discussed for generic functions $f:X\to Y$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll show that for a right-inverse to be unique, the kernel of $\phi$ must vanish, and $\phi$ must therefore be injective.

Write $V = V/\ker(\phi)\oplus \ker(\phi)$ and let $\psi : W \to V/\ker(\phi)\oplus\ker(\phi) $ be a right-inverse.
Then $\psi$ can be written as $\psi = \psi_1 + \psi_0$, where

- $\psi_1 : W \to V/\ker(\phi)$ and
- $\psi_0 : W \to \ker(\phi)$

Composing $\psi_0$ with any automorphism $\mu : \ker(\psi) \to \ker(\psi)$ yields a right-inverse $\psi_\mu = \psi_1 + \mu \circ \psi_0$ with $\phi \circ \psi_\mu = \phi\circ(\psi_1 + \mu \circ \psi_0) = \phi\circ\psi_1 = \phi\circ(\psi_1 + \psi_0) = id_W$.

Comment: You can show analogously that a unique left-inverse implies surjectivity. Note that surjectiv means having a right-inverse and injective means having a left-inverse. The notions are equivalent.

Comment: Hint: use $W=W/\phi(V)\oplus\phi(V)$

Comment: Sorry to resuscitate this post, but I don't why this would work, since $\psi_0$ is obviously $0$, because let $y\in Ker(\phi)\cap \psi(W)$ non zero, $x$ st. $y=\psi(x)$, then $\phi\circ\psi(x)=0\neq x$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The way I thought would solve this is to see that since $\psi$ is injective, $V/Ker(\psi)=V\cong \psi(W)$, so that the codimension of both is $0$, meaning $Ker(\phi)=${$0$}. But I don't seem to have used the unicity of the right inverse... please help ahah

Comment: @Bcpicao You have not actually argued that $\psi_0 = 0$. $\psi_0 = 0$ if and only if $\psi(W) \subset V/\textrm{ker}(\phi)$ (here we identified $V = V/\textrm{ker}(\phi) \oplus \textrm{ker}(\phi)$). Regarding your second comment, the quotient $V/\textrm{ker}(\psi)$ is nonsensical ,as $\textrm{ker}(\psi) \subset W$.
You get $W \simeq \psi(W)$ though.

Comment: For a more concrete picture, imagine $V = \mathbb{R}^2  = \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$, $\psi(W) = \{ (x,y) | x=y \}$ and $\ker(\phi) = \{(x,y) | x = 0 \}$, the $y$-axis. It is indeed the case that $\textrm{ker}(\phi) \cap \psi(W) = 0$, but that does not mean that the points in $\psi(W)$ don't have a $y$-component.

btw, I haven't been here in ages, I just wanted to look up a specific tex-question, when I saw the notification from not even a day ago, what are the odds.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I get it now! I'll think about for a few days to make sure I don't have any further questions. Thank you so much! What a coincidence! ahah

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2438046/144766) provides an answer for $V = W$:

Let $A, B : V \to V$ be linear maps such that $B$ is the unique right inverse for $A$.

We will show that $B$ is also a left inverse for $A$. Consider $BA+B−I$:

$$A(BA+B-I)=ABA+AB-A = A+I-A=I=AB$$

$BA+B-I$ is also a right inverse for $A$. Hence, $BA+B-I=B$, which implies $BA = I$.

Therefore, $A$ is invertible.

Comment: $T$ is not the only right-inverse, take for instance $T'(x_1,...) = (x_1,x_1,x_2,...)$

Comment: Also $S'(x_1,...) = (x_2+x_1,x_3,...)$ is an alternative left inverse

Comment: @Long Thanks, $T$ and $S$ were canonical counterexamples for $TS = I \implies ST = I$ so I got confused.

Comment: $BA$ is a linear map $V \to V$, but $B$ is a linear map $W \to V$. The sum $BA + B$ doesn't makes sense.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ah, yes. It must be $V = W$.