# show invertibility of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

My understanding of this part of linear algebra is somewhat clouded. I fail to see how these two problems are related and/or how to prove them:

1) Show that if $A$ is a linear transformation with $A^2 - A + 1 = 0$, then $A$ is invertible.

2) If $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations on the same vector space and $AB = 1$. Prove that if A has exactly one $right\space inverse\space B$, then A is invertible. (Consider $BA + B - 1$)

---

My Attempt:

1) Show that if $Ax = 0$, then $x$ must be $0$. i.e. $A^2 - A + 1 = 0$ implies $A^2 + 1 = A$, implies $(A^2 + 1)x = Ax$ imples $A(A(x)) + x = A(x)$ imples $A(0) + x = 0$. Since A is linear ($A(0) = 0$), $x = 0$.

2) No idea.

Comment: For (2) show that $BA+B-I$ is also a right inverse of $A$.

Comment: I see the possible duplicate post linked by @Lord Shark the Unknown, but doesn't that solution make problem 2 trivial? In the sense that if I can say A is invertible b/c there exist (1 - A) such that A(1 - A) = 1, I can trivially come to the conclusion in problem 2 that A is invertible sense there exist a B such that AB = 1?

Comment: I read (1) and (2) as independent problems.

Comment: Simple proof of 1): $$A^2-A+1=0 =>A*(1-A)=1 => A^{-1}=1-A$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$$A^2-A+1=0\iff A(1-A)=1$$
and

$$A(BA+B-1)=A+1-A=1=AB$$

Comment: I see the possible duplicate post linked by @Lord Shark the Unknown, or the hint you've given above, but doesn't that solution make problem 2 trivial? In the sense that if I can say A is invertible simply b/c there exist (1 - A) such that A(1 - A) = 1, I can trivially come to the conclusion in problem 2 that A is invertible since there exist a B such that AB = 1?